# Yahoo Exchange Rates not working

Tags: xml, yahoo

I use the yahoo.finance.xchange to get the exchange rates in a XML form which I use for our CRM system. We hit this url to get the wanted XML file:

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22CADZAR%22,%22EURZAR%22,%22GBPZAR%22,%22NADZAR%22,%22USDZAR%22,%22ZARZAR%22,%22CADNAD%22,%22EURNAD%22,%22GBPNAD%22,%22NADNAD%22,%22USDNAD%22,%22ZARNAD%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

This all of a sudden started returning: No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.xchange

[image: XML Table no definition]

Is anybody else having the same issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, https://www.datatables.org/ is down, hope it will start working

Comment: Does anyone know anything about it?  Is it down permanently?... Because 24 hours seems like to much.

Comment: Can't find out anything about it, I hope it starts working again I have built the whole of my University Finals project on top of it lol

Comment: seems it's not completely down, it comes up in several moments and goes down again. now it's night in US, so I hope it will come up soon

Comment: I'll have to rewrite my exchange rates synch app if it doesn't come up soon :(

Answer (score 0):

It's back up again!
Thanks for all the replies guys - appreciated.

[image: XML List]